# bind method in the U_BOOT_DRIVER registration

Tags: u-boot

Why we have `bind` and `probe` two methods in the `U_BOOT_DRIVER`? In Linux with device tree, if the compatible string matches then probe function of the driver will be called to bind the device with the driver. In U-boot why we have additional bind method.

Comment: There are cases where a device cannot be detected or assigned automatically and must be told to bind.  The great majority of drivers do not need `bind` and `unbind` handlers at all.

Answer (score 0):

U-Boot developers try to minimize the boot time. Avoiding access to unused devices helps to reach this target.

In the bind stage the compatible string from the device-tree is used to make U-Boot aware of a device and the driver needed to address it but in this stage the device typically is not accessed.

Probe is typically only called when the device is actually used. In the probe stage the availability of the device is tested and it is set up for usage.

Documentation of U-Boot's driver model is available in https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/develop/driver-model/index.html.